# Limit of decreasing sequence of open sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

There two parts to the problem for a compact set $E$:

1. Define
   $$
   \mathcal{O}_n = \{x \in E: d(x, E) < 1/n \}
   $$
   show that the $m(E) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} m(\mathcal{O}_n)$, where $m$ is the standard Lesbegue measure.
2. Show that the above assertion maybe false if (a) $E$ is closed but unbounded and (b) $E$ is open but bounded.

I have proved all parts except for 2(b). For 2(a) i take $E = \{1,2,3, ... \}$. For 2(b) I am at a loss. Any pointers would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\{q_k\}$ be an enumeration of $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ and define

$$ E = \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb N} ( q_k -2^{-k-2}, q_k+ 2^{-k-2}).$$

Then $m(E) \le 1/2$ and $E$ is open and bounded. But for all $n\in \mathbb N$, since $E$ is dense in $[0,1]$, we have $[0,1] \subset \mathcal O_n$. Thus $m(\mathcal O_n) \ge 1$.

Comment: One point is not clear: that $E$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Is'nt $E \supset [0,1]$. Then how come $\bar{E} = [0,1]$?

Comment: @Iconoclast Why is $E\supset [0,1]$?

Comment: Take $q_k = 0$, then for all $k>0$ the left extremity of $(q_k-2^{-k-2}, q_k+2^{-k-2})$ is below zero. A similar case can be made for the right extremity of the intervals, which falls higher than 1. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Iconoclast Just take $E \cap (0,1)$